# Django activation custom email text does not appear

Tags: django, django-registration

I have both activation_email.txt:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Регистрация на сайте" %}
{% trans "Для активации Вашего аккаунта необходимо перейти по ссылке" %}:
http://{{ site }}{% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}
{% trans "Спасибо" %}!
```

and activation_email_subject.txt:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Активация аккаунта" %} - {{ site }}
```

in my registration folder, but my activation emails dont have text from activation_email.txt, they have some common django message like:

> You (or someone pretending to be you) have asked to register an
>   account at %company%. If this wasn't you, please ignore this email
>   and your address will be removed from our records.
>
> To activate this account, please click the following link within the
>   next 2 days:
>
> %link%
>
> Sincerely, %company% Management

despite the subject is taken from my activation_email_subject.txt file. Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. You must add `REGISTRATION_EMAIL_HTML = False` to you django settings fileto solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as well. Putting `REGISTRATION_EMAIL_HTML = False` in settings allows you to customise the activation_email.txt